# How to convert a timezoned XML type dateTime to time_t with c++

Tags: c++, c, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert 2014-08-19T10:05:33Z to time_t.

My code results to: 1408435533

```
std::string expirationTime("2014-08-19T10:05:33Z");
struct tm tm;
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
strptime(expirationTime.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ", &tm);
time_t timeStamp = mktime(&tm);
printf("time_t for %s is %ld \n\n", expirationTime.c_str(), timeStamp);
```

Result:

```
time_t for 2014-08-19T10:05:33Z is 1408435533
```

But when I am using an online epoch converter I get the following:

```
1408435533
Is equivalent to:

08/19/2014 @ 8:05am (UTC)
2014-08-19T08:05:33+00:00 in ISO 8601
```

which seems to be wrong since there are 2 h time difference.

Comment: Have you considered about your time zone? can you tell weather your code modifies time with current time zone (i.e. UTC+offset ). The online result is for UTC.

Comment: The code as seen above, it does not modify time. Based on the string provided "2014-08-19T10:05:33Z", how can I extract the timezone offset?Thanks!

Comment: You can try to convert current time epoch with your code and online converter. Compare those results. If the difference matches to offset for your time zone,just subtract it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only, cross-platform, datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you can do it like this:

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::string expirationTime("2014-08-19T10:05:33Z");
    std::istringstream in{expirationTime};
    sys_seconds timeStamp;
    in >> parse("%Y-%m-%dT%TZ", timeStamp);
    std::cout << "timeStamp is " << timeStamp.time_since_epoch() 
              << " which is "    << timeStamp << '\n';
}
```

This builds on top of the `std::chrono` library which was introduced with C++11.  The above program outputs:

```
timeStamp is 1408442733s which is 2014-08-19 10:05:33
```

Answer (score 0):

see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html
Use timegm instead of mktime, but I think it is not available for Windows

Answer (score 0):

> seems to be wrong since there are 2 h time difference.

[mktime - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/):

> ```
> time_t mktime (struct tm * timeptr);
> ```
>
> Convert tm structure to time_t
>
> Returns the value of type time_t that represents the local time
>   described by the [tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/tm) structure pointed
>   by timeptr (which may be modified).

Since it returns *the local time*, you have to adjust for the `timezone` if you want UTC; insert

```
    extern long timezone;
    timeStamp += timezone;
```